# List sub directories of a folder in APPDATA using Windows JScript

Tags: winapi, registry, jscript.net

I'm trying to edit a json file which is located inside a folder in `AppData\Roaming`.

The file path is `AppData\Roaming\Myapp\RANDOM_CRAP\settings.json`

`RANDOM_CRAP` is just a random folder name which is different for every machine.
In order to open this file for writing, I first tried to get it's file path, like so:

```
function getAppData() {
   var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
   var strValue = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\User Shell Folders\\AppData");
   return strValue;
}
```

Problem is, the value stored under that registry key is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` which doesn't seem to open with:

```
var folder = fso.GetFolder(getAppData());
```

(Throws `Path not found` error)
Can I get to the APPDATA path in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Getting to AppData path is easy with the [ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Party time:

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Echo("WinDir is " + WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%"));
```

Good luck.